# A sequence of simple functions

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and $f\colon X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ a non-negative measurable function. For each $j\in\mathbb{N}$ set
> >     $$
> > f_j:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{j2^j}\frac{k-1}{2^j}\chi_{A_{j,k}}+j\chi_{B_j}
> > $$
> >     with
> >     $$
> > A_{j,k}:=f^{-1}\left(\left(\frac{k-1}{2^j},\frac{k}{2^j}\right]\right),~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~B_j:=f^{-1}((j,\infty])
> > $$
> >     Show that: 1) Each $f_j$ is a non-negative measurable simple function. 2) The sequence $(f_j)$ increases monotonously. 3) The sequence $(f_j)$ converges pointwise against $f$.

ad 1) Each function $f_j$ takes $j2^j+1$ non-negative values, which are $j$ and $\frac{k-1}{2^j}, k=1,...,j2^j$. So the only thing which I still have to show is the measurability of each $f_j$. How can I do so?

ad 2) When $x\in B_j$, then $x\in B_{j+1}$ or $x$ is element of one of those $A_{j+1,k}$ which together cover $(j+,j+1]$. In both cases it is $f_j(x)\leq f_{j+1}(x)$. When $x\in A_{j,k}$, then $x\in A_{j+1,2k-1}$ or $x\in A_{j+1,2k}$. So it is $f_j(x)\leq f_{j+1}(x)$.

ad 3) Let $x\in X$ be fixed. Then $x\in A_{j,k}$ for a $j\in\mathbb{N}$ and a $k\in\left\{1,...,j2^j\right\}$ or $x\in B_j$. Then
$$
\lvert f_j(x)-f(x)\rvert\leq\frac{2k-1}{2^j}\to 0, j\to\infty.
$$
Now I have to treat the case that $x\in B_j$. But unfortunately I do not come along wit that; I have
$$
\lvert f_j(x)-f(x)\rvert=\lvert j-f(x)\rvert\leq 2f(x)
$$
but do not know how to work with that or how to continue that.

Comment: $f_j$ is a sum of measurable functions sind the sets $A_{j,k}$ and $B_j$ are measurable. Since $B_j$ is "shrinking" you won't find $x\in B_j$ for large $j$. Another remark: If you find a bound for every $x$ you can at least get convergence against some function. Maybe this can also help.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I got the measurability now. But to be honest I did not understand what you meant concerning the convergence when the fixed $x$ is within $B_j$.

Comment: if you choose $j$ large enough $x\not\in B_j$. Large enough means $j>|x|$. Hence the second term in $f_j$ always converges to zero. Hence if the first term in $f_j$ converges to $f$ so does the whole $f_j$ (Of course thinking in terms of improper limits)

Comment: Now I understood. Thank you very much! By the way: Is my proof, that the first term converges to $f$ okay?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand your proof. I haven't yet figured out the first estimate inculding $f$. This is too fast for me (at the moment)

Comment: If $x$ is fixed and $j$, too and when $x$ is not in $B_j$ then it's in one $A_{j,k}$, what means $f_j(x)=\frac{k-1}{2^j}$ and $f(x)\leq\frac{k}{2^j}$. Then $\lvert f_j(x)-f(x)\rvert\leq f_j(x)+f(x)\leq\frac{k-1+k}{2^j}\to 0, j\to\infty$. That was my idea and I hope it's okay. :D

Comment: Why should $f$ be bounded? the function maps is allowed to take values at $\infty$. I think your prove will not work that way. What is the sequence $f_j$ doing? The increase of $j$ has 2 effects: 1. increasing $j$ leads to a higher "cutting" off of $f$. Concerning $B_j$ you can think on that set of $f_j=\min\{j,f(x)\}$. The other effect is that you get a more and more precise feeling of $f$ on the set where $f$ is "small$. i.e for $j=1$, $f_j$ has values $1,1/2$ and $1$. For $j=2$ you can have steps of $1/4$-size leading to $0,1/4,2/4,3/4,1,5/4,3/2,7/4,2$

Comment: Of course f is not bounded. But if I have a fixed x then it is in an $A_{j,k}$ or an $B_j$ for a special $j$. If it is in an $A_{j,k}$ then $f(x)\in (-\frac{k-1}{2^j},\frac{k}{2^j}]$ and therefore for that fixed $x$ it is $f(x)\leq \frac{k}{2^j}$ and I used that to proof that the difference between $f_j(x)$ and $f(x)$ converges to $0$ when $j\to\infty$.

Comment: okay, there you are right. However a problem is that $k$ is allowed to increase as $j$ does! So the "uniform" bound $f(x)\leq k/2^j$ does indeed depend on $k$ and $j$. So i fear sending $j$ to zero could lead to $k$ sending to $2^j$

Comment: I do not see the Problem, sorry. If the fixed $x$ lies in a $A_{j,k}$ then it lies also in $A_{j+1,2k-1}$ or in $A_{j+1,2k}$. Nevertheless the limit of $f(x)$ remains $\frac{k}{2^j}$. So I do not see why the limit depends on $k$, too. Because the first k that belongs to the $A_{j,k}$ remains the k which belongs to the limit of $f(x)$ for $f_{j+1}(x), f_{j+2}(x),...$.

Comment: but then you can't increase $j$. as you said: $f(x)\leq k\2^j=2k/2^{j+1}$ so you increased $j$ but you won't go to zero!

Comment: I guess I again do not understand what you mean. ;(

Comment: Yo said you estimated $|f_j-f|\leq \frac{2k-1}{2^j}$. However $k$ depends on $j$.  So if $j$ goes to infinity so could $k$. Hence it is not clear what the limit of $\frac{2k-1}{2^j}$ really is. Think of $f\equiv 1$. Then any $x$ is  in the set $A_{j,2^j}=((2^j- 1)/2^j, 2^j/2^j])$ and $f_j$ takes the values $(2^j-1)/2^j$ which clearly converges to one. However we find $k=2^j$ and this goes to infinity as $1/2^j$ goes to zero

Comment: But I do not understand why $k$ depends on $j$! The k is a fixed  value that is determined by the $A_{j,k}$ in which the fixed x is for  a starting $j$. And then $j$ goes to infinity. But k remains the same.

Comment: no it is not :) if you increase $j$ you have to recalulate $k$. Just try it with $f\equiv 1$. In you above estimate you are even saying that $0\leq f_j+f \to 0$. How should this be possible. For$f=1$ and since $f_j$ is nonnegative this is obviously false. Maybe you should try to draw for a simple stepfunction $f$ (mabye with values $1/3,0$ and $1$) and the approximating sequence $f_j$. I hope that then everything becomes clearer

Comment: Okay, I understand what you meant. I understood it with the following example: Let $f$ be a step function taking the values $0,1/3, 1$ and pick a fixed $x$. Let $x\in f^{-1}(\left\{1/3\right\})$. Then $f_1(x)=1/2$ and the related preimage is $A_{1,2}$. And $f_2(x)=1/4$ with related preimage $A_{2,2}$, $f_3(x)=1/4$ with related preimage $A_{3,3}$, $f_4(x)=5/16$ with related preimage $A_{4,6}$ and so on. Now I see what you meant. But as a consequence now I do not know how to prove that $f_j(x)\to f(x), j\to\infty$. It seems that one has to prove it totally different as I tried.

Comment: your function has to be non-decreasing, hence the value should be below 1/3 namely 0 :)

Comment: What irritated me, too, is that its not $f_j(x)\leq f_{j+1}(x)$ but concerning the task the sequence is increasing monotonously.

Comment: Why does it have to be non-decreasing?.-..

Comment: right, thats what I mentioned above :). Ideas for a proof: 1. you could check if you can improve your estimate. 2. A non-decreasing bounded sequence converges. So can you show that $f_j(x)\leq f(x)$ for every $x$? So you would get convergence of $f_j(x)\to g(x)$ where $f$ is bounded. Can you show that $g\geq f$? On the set where $f$ is not bounded does $f_j$ also go to infty?

Comment: you proved that it is non-decreasing ( or as you said monotonously increasing)

Comment: I would like to improve my estimation but do not know how to do so.

Comment: Neither do i. If this is possible I think you should try to write $f$ also as a series (since it is measurbale it can be approximated by simple functions) but I think your $f_j$ is one of the standard approaches to write $f$ as a limit of simple functions. Hence I think it would be better to perform the second idea. But maybe both approaches are the same :) I'm sorry but I'm not sure. Maybe I'll think about it.

Comment: But what is that $g(x)$ you mentioned under 2)?

Comment: Please do not think I am crazy, but i still do not see the mistake! $x$ is fixed. Then $\lvert\sum\limits_{k=1}^{j2^j}\frac{k-1}{2^j}\chi_{A_{j,k}}(x)-f(x)\rvert=\lvert \frac{k-1}{2^j}-f(x)\rvert$ when $x\in f^{-1}((\frac{k-1}{2^j},\frac{k}{2^j}])=A_{j,k}$. So $f(x)\leq \frac{k}{2^j}$. ;( And now I estimate with triangle inequation $\lvert \frac{k-1}{2^j}-f(x)\rvert\leq \lvert\frac{k-1}{2^j}\rvert+f(x)$. Sorry, for me its no problem at all. Maye I quit here.

Comment: ofcourse the last estimate is right but you won't find convegrence to zero there and furthermore: increasing $j$ which is equivalent with a higher resolution of the intervals can lead to an increase of $k$ as you proved above! I meant convergence against some function $g$ you don't know it it converges to $f$. However, I think what you can prove is that $|f_j(x)-f(x|\leq 1/2^j$ and then you get the convergence on the set where $f$ is bounded

Comment: How do you get the equation?

Comment: as you said, if we are on $A_{j,k}$ we find $|f-f_j|=f-f_j\leq k/2^j -(k-1)/2^j\leq 1/2^j$ since the largest value on the set of  if $k/2^j$. Note that this estimates holds for every $j,k$ as long as we are in the case that $f(x)\leq j$

Comment: I think finally I got it: There are two cases for a fixed $x\in X$: (a) $f(x)<\infty$: Then for $j\in\mathbb{N}$ big enough (i.e. for all $j\geq f(x)$) it is $\lvert f_j(x)-f(x)\rvert\leq 2^{-j}$ and so for $j\to\infty$ it is $\lvert f_j(x)-f(x)\rvert\to 0$. (b) $f(x)=\infty$: Then for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$ it is $f_j(x)=j$ (because of $f(x)=\infty >j$) and so $f_j(x)\to \infty=f(x)$. -- Now it should be finished after a long long discussion and many mistakes that I made.

Comment: that sounds correct :)

Comment: I am very thankful for your patient help! Have a nice weekend!